# How to customize the package editor interface?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, customization, interface

Is there a way to get rid of the unused space on the left of the package editor?

[image]

What is it's purpose if I configured *Mathematica* to not show `In` and `Out` names? (Using *Mathematica* 10.1).

Comment: I suppose it would be nice if that was tweakable, but it's probably not.

Comment: @Kuba nice nice, your answer makes a lot of sense :P. I'll try to remember `CellMargins` :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks :)

Comment: Related: [How to set Initialization Cell style to conform with custom stylesheet?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123668/89).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Quick fix for a specific file:**

  Ok, let's open new package `File -> New -> Package`.

  It was second on my list of `Notebooks[]`. So:

  ```
  package = Notebooks[][[2]]
  ```

  This is a notebook as any other, it just has different stylesheet (`"Package.nb"`) and we can modify it as any other:

  ```
  SetOptions[ package, {
    StyleDefinitions ->  Notebook[{
       Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Package.nb"]], 
       Cell[StyleData["Code"], CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
    }],
    ShowCellLabel -> False,
    ShowGroupOpener -> False}
  ]
  ```

  (*notice that we are styling "Code" cell as this is the default one*)

  > [image]

---

- **General approach to modifying built in stylesheets**

  This was set just for that .m file. If you want to set it globally edit the `Package.nb` stylesheet.

  It is not so easy, you need privileges to work in `$InstallationDirectory`, system packages are not `Editable` and you risk breaking base files.

  Here is a way to go to avoid those problems: copy stylesheet to the `$UserBaseDirectory`, enable editing and do whatever you need:

  ```
  CopyFile @@ ( FileNameJoin[
    {#, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", "Package.nb"}
  ] & /@ {
   $InstallationDirectory, $UserBaseDirectory
  })

  SetOptions[NotebookOpen @ %, {Editable -> True, Saveable -> True}]
  ```

---

[Learned from Verbeia](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64059/5478)

Comment: Very well, worked, thanks! Any problems on doing that? Any info that could be hidden besides the In e Out messages?

Comment: @Giovanni `In` and `Out` are still available, you just can't see which cells they  are referring to.

Comment: @Giovanni you could also lose the information whether the cell was evaluated in debug mode and possibly CellTags/cell labels could become invisible. All of these do not seem really standard for package development though.