# Where is the file Default.nb?

Tags: stylesheet, style

I've found a couple of files called Default.nb under my Mathematica installation, but they don't seem to have any effect.  At any rate, neither of them was changed when I edited <sup>1</sup> the so-called `Default.nb` stylesheet a few minutes ago.  (They both still have modification time from the time I first installed Mathematica.)

I want to find the actual notebook so I can edit it using a text editor<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> To edit "Default.nb" I clicked on **Format > Edit Stylesheet...**, which brings up a "styles" notebook whose first cell says *Inheriting base definitions from stylesheet "Default.nb"* followed by a clickable link to Default.nb.  Clicking on this link brings up a similar notebook titled ***Default.nb style definitions***, but I can't determine where this notebook is stored.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> The idea of editing this notebook using the Format menu is a joke in poor taste.  Not only is it grossly inefficient timewise, it wouldn't be adequate even if one had infinite time.  The Format menu is just too blunt a tool.  One can't, for example, change a font family without also being forced to specify its font size, weight, etc.  Customizations via the Format menu would be grossly over-specified.</sup>

Comment: Try `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrondEnd", 
  "StyleSheets"}]`

Comment: Michael E2 has given you the location, but I say: never, never edit any file in that directory. Rather build a new style be deriving one from one the files in that directory.

Comment: Here is an example how to edit Package stylesheet: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/5478

Comment: During the `StyleSheet` modification you cannot save the modified file by `Menu/File/Save`. You need to use `Menu/File/SaveAs` even if you have already saved it once. However, I join to m_goldenberg warning: never, never change `Default.nb`. Make better something like `Default-modified.nb`, as I did for myself. You will need to assign each new notebook to this style, but you will be on the safe side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleSheetPath.html),

> `StyleSheetPath` is a global option that specifies which directories the Wolfram System searches to find stylesheets.
>
> The directories to be searched are specified using the `` FrontEnd`FileName `` function. Typical directories included in `StyleSheetPath` are `` FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory,"SystemFiles","FrontEnd","StyleSheets"}] `` and `` FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory,"SystemFiles", "FrontEnd","StyleSheets"}] ``.

In *Mathematica* 10.4.1 the value of this option itself is not very informative:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, StyleSheetPath]
```

> ```
> {StyleSheetPath -> {ParentList, 
>    FrontEnd`FileName[{"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
> Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\SystemFiles\\Components\\MUnit\\FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}, 
>     "PacletManager" -> True]}}
> ```

Fortunately, `AbsoluteOptions` works here:

```
AbsoluteOptions[$FrontEnd, StyleSheetPath]

{StyleSheetPath -> {
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Autoload", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory, "Autoload", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory, "Applications", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Autoload", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "AddOns", "Applications", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$BaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "Configuration", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", _, "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}], 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.4\\SystemFiles\\Components\\MUnit\\FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}, 
                     "PacletManager" -> True]
         }}
```

The built-in stylesheets are located in the directory

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrondEnd", "StyleSheets"}]
```

As [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) correctly notes in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113518/where-is-the-file-default-nb#comment308199_113518), it is strongly recommended do not edit the built-in stylesheets directly. The recommended way is to make a copy of the built-in stylesheet in the directory

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}]
```

with another name, then **remove the `Saveable -> False` option**, and then edit it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also find things like these using the (undocumented and dangerous) `` FrontEnd`FindFileOnPath ``.

I implemented a safer wrapper for it [here](https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/45736b3cab82aa692964b24a00268c88301c5d60/Packages/FETools.m#L855) which can also spit out the path it found for it:

```
FEFindFileOnPath["Default.nb",
 "ReturnKey" -> True]

"StyleSheetPath" -> \
"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/\
StyleSheets/Default.nb"
```