# How to set Initialization Cell style to conform with custom stylesheet?

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, cells

In version 11, initialization cells [got a dedicated style](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/user-interface-enhancements/improved-initialization-cells.html?product=mathematica) which has a light gray background. **How can I ensure that the background of this type of cell conforms to the actual stylesheet?**

Compare below the two basic stylesheets, **ReverseColor** and **Default**. The initialization cell is barely readable with the reversed stylesheet.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add to the private stylesheet or edit the `ReverseColor.nb` with

```
Cell[StyleData["InitializationCell"], Background->GrayLevel[0]]
```

because it was missed somehow. E.g. "Code" cell has this fixed already:

```
Cell[StyleData["Code"],
  FontColor->GrayLevel[0.9],
  Background->GrayLevel[0]
]
```

p.s. Built in stylesheets can be edited safely when moved from `$InstallationDirectory` to appropriate directory in e.g `$UserBaseDirectory`. An example: [Package editor interface](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/5478)

To make the copied stylesheet file editable, open **Option Inspector** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), make sure that the **Show option values** field says **Selected Notebook**, find **Notebook options** > **File options** > **Editable** and set it to `True`.

Comment: I'd report that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kuba. Actually I've already reported it before posting here, but they are slower to provide a workaround, so I expected that someone here already knows the answer.