# Style options to make initialization cells appear like regular cells?

Tags: cells, style, stylesheet, appearance

I find the discontinuous grey rectangles around those cells to be distracting. Any way I can make them look like regular cells?

Comment: Closely related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123668/5478