# Setting Stylesheet for Package files in Version 11.1

Tags: front-end, packages, stylesheet

Since many versions the frontend does a pretty good job as an editor for package files (.m or .wl). In versions up to 11.1 code as the following could be used to additionally tweak the appearance and behavior of the package files in the frontend:

```
NotebookSave[Notebook[{
  Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Package.nb"]],
  Cell[StyleData["Code"], CellFrame -> 3, 
    CellMargins -> {{55, 3}, {4, 4}}, 
    CellFrameColor -> RGBColor[0.1, 0.6, 0.1]]
}], FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "mypckgstyle.nb"}]];

Export[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "dummy.m"}],
  "f[x_]:=x^2;",
  "Text"
];

pckgstyle=CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "DefaultPackageStyleDefinitions"];
 CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "DefaultPackageStyleDefinitions"] = 
   FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "mypckgstyle.nb"}];

NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Desktop", "dummy.m"}]];

CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, "DefaultPackageStyleDefinitions"] = pckgstyle;
```

what that code does is to define a new stylesheet which inherits from the default "Package.nb" stylesheets and changes some details about "Code" cells. It then generates a dummy package file and opens it, using the new stylesheet. After that it restores the original settings for the frontend setting "DefaultPackageStyleDefinitions". If executing this with version < 11.1 you should find the code cells have a thick green frame.

With version 11.1 that seems to not work anymore, some of the settings in such a stylesheet will not be respected but overridden by the settings from "Package.nb", among those the `CellFrame` and `CellFrameColor` options. Interestingly other settings will work as expected and as in older versions. Has anyone an explanation for the behavior? What I am doing is not really well documented so I am hesitating to call it a bug, on the other hand I don't see how the new behavior could be justified to be better than what the old was...

Any explanation or workarounds would be appreciated and accepted as answers.

Comment: Are you aware of https://github.com/kubaPod/MoreStyles ? Works for me in 11.1. Of course this does not exactly answer your question, but may be a starting point.

Comment: @RolfMertig: no, I was not aware of that. Will have a look at it, probably this weekend. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @AlbertRetey Your issue is that the style you need to change is `"InitializationCell"`, not `"Code"`. That's where `"CellFrame*"` is defined in `"Package.nb"`.

Comment: @MB1965: I think your comment will solve my problem, if you make it an answer I will accept it. If you have any background information I will appreciate that. It looks like any cell that has `InitializationCell->True` set will inherit from styledata from "InitializationCell", no matter what its actual style is. I think either the behavior or one of the stylesheets has changed in version 11.1, but maybe it only does now behave as was originally intended...

Comment: @AlbertRetey I was actually in the process of writing up a much longer and involved answer when you posted that. That gives another overkill way to do this.

Comment: slightly related: [**126517**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126517/5478)

Comment: good point, and confirms that indeed a bit more than just the stylesheet definition must have changed somewhere between version 10 and 11.1 ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Simple Answer

So I mentioned in a comment that your method will work. The only issue is that there is a style specification with higher precedence that gets applied after your styles. If you look at `"Package.nb"` they use `"InitializationCell"` to specify the `CellFrameColor` and whatnot. If you override that style instead you're golden.

Since 11.0 (I believe) the `"InitializationCell"` style gets applied to anything with `InitializationCell -> True`. `"InitializationCell"` is much like `StandardForm` in that it's applied after standard `Cell` styles (and so has higher precedence).

#### Overkill Answer

On the other hand, you can actually edit the `"Package.nb"` styles in place without overwriting the file. This will be a code-intensive answer, so I'll put it all in one block at the end.

First off we need a way to find the style cells. This is relatively easy. We'll do a very simple match. Matching more syntax and vectorizing would be better (I've done that for myself) but requires many more lines of code.

```
cellMatchQ[Cell[StyleData[name : Except[_Rule], ___], ___], style_] :=

    Switch[{name, style},
   {_String, _String | _StringExpression | _Alternatives},
   StringMatchQ[name, style],
   _,
   MatchQ[name, style]
   ];
StylesheetCells[nb_NotebookObject, style_] :=
  Select[Cells[nb],
   cellMatchQ[NotebookRead@#, style] &
   ];
```

Then we need a system for editing the cells:

```
StylesheetApplyEdits[cells : {__CellObject}] :=

  With[{e = EvaluationCell[]},
   Do[
    SelectionMove[c, All, Cell,
     AutoScroll -> False];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"]; 
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"];,
    {c, cells}
    ];
   SelectionMove[e, After, Cell]
   ];

Options[StylesheetEdit] =
  Options@Cell;
StylesheetEdit[cells : {__CellObject}, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  (
   Do[SetOptions[c, ops], {c, cells}];
   StylesheetApplyEdits@cells;
   );
StylesheetEdit[nb_NotebookObject, style_, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

   Replace[StylesheetCells[nb, style], {
    {} -> Null,
    c : {__} :> StylesheetEdit[c, ops]
    }];
```

Note that the `ApplyEdits` call is necessary so the cascade updates properly.

Now we'll use a method for selecting stylesheet notebooks to thread this all together:

```
$PackageStyleNotebook :=

 SelectFirst[FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd], 
  Quiet@NotebookFileName@# === 
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
      "StyleSheets", "Package.nb"} &]
```

If there are any packages open, this will return the `NotebookObject` that defines their styles.

Now we can use this as such:

```
StylesheetEdit[$PackageStyleNotebook, "InitializationCell",
 CellFrameColor -> Pink
 ]
```

Note that this doesn't save any style changes. So every time you close the last of your package notebooks all your styles will get erased. But this can be applied to *any* style notebook. Which is what makes it fun and powerful. For myself I've also added a `StylesheetNew` function that will write appropriately configured cells to a notebook, and that can be used with this functionality to easily add new styles.

This is overkill, but fun and flexible overkill.

Now, as promised, here's everything in a block:

```
cellMatchQ[Cell[StyleData[name : Except[_Rule], ___], ___], style_] :=

    Switch[{name, style},
   {_String, _String | _StringExpression | _Alternatives},
   StringMatchQ[name, style],
   _,
   MatchQ[name, style]
   ];
StylesheetCells[nb_NotebookObject, style_] :=
  Select[Cells[nb],
   cellMatchQ[NotebookRead@#, style] &
   ];

StylesheetApplyEdits[cells : {__CellObject}] :=

  With[{e = EvaluationCell[]},
   Do[
    SelectionMove[c, All, Cell,
     AutoScroll -> False];
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"]; 
    FrontEndTokenExecute[ParentNotebook@c, "ToggleShowExpression"];,
    {c, cells}
    ];
   SelectionMove[e, After, Cell]
   ];

Options[StylesheetEdit] =
  Options@Cell;
StylesheetEdit[cells : {__CellObject}, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  (
   Do[SetOptions[c, ops], {c, cells}];
   StylesheetApplyEdits@cells;
   );
StylesheetEdit[nb_NotebookObject, style_, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=

   Replace[StylesheetCells[nb, style], {
    {} -> Null,
    c : {__} :> StylesheetEdit[c, ops]
    }];

$PackageStyleNotebook :=

 SelectFirst[FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`ObjectChildren[$FrontEnd], 
  Quiet@NotebookFileName@# === 
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
      "StyleSheets", "Package.nb"} &]
```

Comment: thanks, interesting answer which is appreciated. One thing I would like to have more explanation is why it is **wrong** to change the "Code" style for "Code" cells as that is overwritten by the "InitializationCell" style. It seems to me to be a peculiarity that would be worth mentioning somewhere in the documentation (which it might be, but where?). It isn't something that is self-explanatory, is it?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Sorry, maybe **wrong** is the **wrong** word ;) It's just that it has higher application precedence, just like `StandardForm`. I edited the answer to include that. I'll also edit out the wrong.

Comment: @AlbertRetey I think we can understand the higher application precedence of `"InitializationCell"` as coming from the fact that it's turned on and off at the `Option` level of a cell, just like `StandardForm` wraps around boxes and whatnot--i.e. more deeply nested than cell. Interestingly, `"InitializationCell"` actually takes precedence over `StandardForm`, I found.

Comment: well, after all it was the **wrong** way to achieve my goal :-). How did you find about those precedences, just by experimenting? Now that I know they exist they make sense to some extent, but it would of course be nice if one would have a chance to look up which precedence rules do exist...

Comment: by the way, your latest change makes me like your answer much better, and not only because it makes me look less of an idiot :-), well deserved bounty!

Comment: @AlbertRetey I found about them the hard way--code I expected to work didn't. Try setting `LineSpacing -> {0, 1}` on the `"Code"` style. It doesn't do anything. And that's because the `BoxData` enforces `StandardForm`, which has a different spec. On the other hand if you set that on `"InitializationCell"` it actually *does* do something. That shows that `"InitializationCell"` applied *after* `StandardForm` does.