# Changing Color of error messages

Tags: front-end, color, customization, stylesheet

I would like to change (from the stylesheet) the colors of the error messages. For example, trying to evaluate

`Solve[wrongsyntax = 0, var]`
gives an obvious error message. The `Solve` from the error message is in red and the `message/comment` is in gray. Is there a way to change these colors? I tried via `AutoStyleOptions`, but none of the options seemed to affect either.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow steps in [**this answer**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/81016/5478) to create *Default.nb* in your `$UserBaseDirectory`. (replace Package.nb with Default.nb first!)

Then add those style cells:

```
Cell[StyleData["MessageMenuLabel"], FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]

Cell[StyleData["MessageText"], FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]
```

You may need to restart MMA but it should work:

[image]

How did I know which styles? Ctrl+Shift+E reveals styles used in messages:

> ```
> Cell[BoxData[
>   TemplateBox[{ "Solve","naqs", ...},  "MessageTemplate"]], 
>   "MessagesWindowMessage", "MSG", ShowCellLabel->True, ...
> ]
> ```

And `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "MessageTemplate"}]` reveals `DisplayFunction`:

> ```
> {TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{
>     TooltipBox[
>       ..., 
>       RowBox[{#1, "::", #2}], BaseStyle -> "MessageMenuLabel"
>     ], 
>    ":", " ", StyleBox[#3, "MessageText"]}] &), ...
>    }
> ```