# How to make warning and errors messages on console print in RED? so easy to see them?

Tags: front-end, warning-messages, output-formatting, color

When I run large computation with 1,000's of iterations, then later look at the console looking for any errors or warnings generated, it is hard to locate them scrolling up and down, as the color of the messages by default is gray, which is close to the black color used for normal print output.

Is there a way to change the color so they are red?

There was a similar question here [changing-color-of-error-messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193420/changing-color-of-error-messages) but looking at it, it is for messages going to the notebook itself, not the console. And it requires changing the whole notebook default style as I understood the answer, which I do not think will have any effect as my messages go to the console?

I actually also tried to do what the above answer says which is to `Then add those style cells:` but  I had no idea how do that. How does one add new cell styles to a notebook? I looked at option at top of the notebook and see no option to add a cell style?

Here is a typical screen shot of the console showing what I mean

[image]

With 10's of thousands of lines, it is easier to spot these if they were in red while scrolling looking for the message when I hear a beep.

I have the following at the top of my notebook before starting the computation

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"PrintAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole"}
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {"MessageOptions", 
   "KernelMessageAction"}] = {"PrintToConsole", "Beep"}
```

This causes everything (including normal Print) to go to console so I do not clutter the notebook.

I just need the color of any error or warning in the console to be red so easy to see. Any option in options inspector to do this easily?

V 13.0.1 on windows.

Comment: `$MessagePrePrint = Style[#, Red, 18, Bold] &;` ? Also take a look at `$SyntaxHandler`.

Comment: @Syed thanks for the suggestion. But this did not do exactly what I wanted. I did `$MessagePrePrint = Style[#, Red, 18, Bold] &;` then `DSolve[y'[x] == 1, y, z]` the error message on console still printed in gray by `DSolve` Also when I did `1/0` it showed only the `1/0` in red, but the rest of the message still in gray. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry8bI.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The style of a message is controlled by the setting for "MessageText". You can modify the stylesheet for the messages notebook with:

```
SetOptions[
    MessagesNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData["MessageText"], FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

Then, messages should be printed in red.